# Is it normal to obtain different test results with different batch sizes with tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using tensorflow for a classification problem.

I have some utility for saving and loading my network. When I restore the network, I can specify a different batch size than for training.

My problem is that I am getting different test results when I restore with a different batch size. However, there is no difference when using the same batch size.

EDIT: Please note that I am not using dropout.

The difference is between 0% and 1% (0.5% on average).

My network is a fully connected layer that predicts two different outputs. I did not have the issue when I only had one task to predict.

My loss op is a sum of both losses.

What could be the issue? Does it have to do with Tensorflow's parallelization strategy?

Comment: Are you using dropout ?

Comment: I have put 0 dropout both for training and testing.

Comment: Are you using batch normalization?

Comment: Are you going through the entire test set every time, even when your test sample number is not a multiple of the batch size?

Comment: @nessuno I am not using batch normalization.
user1735003 I have considered this. Hence, I have been dropping out some batches to make sure I have the same number of data points.

Comment: You have the same number of data points but do you have the same data exactly ? Could you select a fix number of testing data, let say 1024, then measure the performances with 32 batches of size 32, 16 of size 64 and 8 of size 128?

Comment: so your test set size is now a multiple of all the different batch sizes you are testing?

Comment: @xiawi. The batches are the same. I have checked that several times. I have been using multiples of both the training and restoring batch_size each time.

Comment: Is your training set balanced?

Comment: Are you using a GPU or CPU ? As well, could you identify example of outputs that are different (according to batch size) and display how much they are ?
possibly see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8670

"(...)I think this could be related with the full connected layers with a lot of inputs/outputs. Somehow the operations are not performed in the same order and the round error is different per batch size, this leads to an accumulation of the error different per batch size. When the layers are big (1024 neurons) the error adds and the output is completely different."

Comment: @nesunno Not really. I am dealing with Natural language processing, so the occurrence of certain classes are rare by nature.
I am using a TITAN-X GPU. For example, out of 24977 instances I got 486 differences in out task and 255 in another one

Comment: @user1735003 I am using a pipeline. RNN to encode context then fully connected layer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

This normally means that you did not set the `phase_train` parameter back to `false` after testing.